# Sankey Diagram unable to deliver using the json output

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram

Using data from database I am trying to simulate the sankey diagram [working JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/mailsakthi/sedtrg03/33/)

I am assembling my data using the below code

```
// sdata.php
<?php
$con = sqlsrv_connect($server, $options);
if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . sqlsrv_error());}
$sql_query = "select * from test_data";
$result = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql_query);
$series = array(); 
$series['type'] = 'sankey'; 
$series['name'] = 'Gendata'; 
$series['keys'] = '[\'from\',\'to\',\'weight\']'; 

while($r = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
$series1 = array(); 
$series1[] = $r['PARENT']; 
$series1[] = $r['CHILD']; 
$series1[] = $r['DGEN'];
$series['data'][] = $series1;
}
$result = array(); 
array_push($result,$series); 
print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); 
sqlsrv_close($con);
?>
```

My JSON looks like

```
    [{
   "type":"sankey",
   "name":"Gendata",
   "keys":"['from','to','weight']",
   "data":[
      ["GROUP","COAL",24.46], ["GROUP","GAS",11.96],["GROUP","HYDRO",19.36],
      ["HYDRO","HYD",19.36], ["COAL","ER2",22.4],["GAS","NR",19]
          ]
    }]
```

My Chart rending code looks like

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var options = {
          chart: {
           renderTo: 'container',
            showAxes: true
                 },
          yAxis: [{
            lineWidth: 1,
            tickPositions: [0, 1, 2, 3]
                 }],
          title: {
                text: 'Sankey Diagram'
                 },
          series: []
}
$.getJSON("sdata.php", function(resp) {
 console.log(resp);
 options.series[0] = resp[1]; //option 1 to assign the data in series
 //options.series.push.resp; //option 2 to push the data in series
 chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
});
```

but I am failing. I am unable to find the error I am missing
 
Kindly help me.

Let me know if I can be of any further information.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have posted here, the error is your `keys` assignment.

You have:

```
"keys":"['from','to','weight']",
```

But it needs to be:

```
"keys": ['from','to','weight'],
```

That is, the array should not be surrounded by quotes, because then it will be interpreted as a string.

In your PHP that would mean:

```
$series['keys'] = '[\'from\',\'to\',\'weight\']';
```

Needs to be:

```
$series['keys'] = ['from', 'to', 'weight'];
```

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/aeh02djx/

Comment: Can you please also let me know how I should form the data array before json_encode. Currently I am forming the data array using the below method, 
$series = array(); 
$series['type'] = 'sankey'; 
$series['name'] = 'Gendata'; 
$series['keys'] = '[\'from\',\'to\',\'weight\']';

Comment: Updated answer, with PHP part.